# How to eliminate some showing details that I don't want to show?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am novice with ruby on rails and I am trying to show just the email of the user but all user's field are also shown and I don't understand where is the problem.

This is my index method in `users_controller`

```
def index
@users=User.all
end
```

This is my `index.html.erb`:

```
<h1>Users#index</h1>
<%= link_to 'Register', new_user_url %><br/>
<ul>
<%= @users.each  do |user| %>
<li><%= user.email %></li><br/>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

What server returns:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-14 12:15:44 +0100
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
  User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
  Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (21.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 38796ms (Views: 38714.2ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
<%= @users.each  do |user| %>
```

should be replaced with

```
<% @users.each  do |user| %>
```

The `<%=` at the beginning means not only processing this line but also display the result. `<%` means only processing, not displaying.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an equals sign in front of the @users.each line. Try this.

```
<h1>Users#index</h1>
<%= link_to 'Register', new_user_url %><br/>
<ul>
<% @users.each  do |user| %>
<li><%= user.email %></li><br/>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying `<%= @users.each  do |user| %>` so it will displays all users which are in **@users** variable. so remove the "=" in erb code so add this line `<% @users.each  do |user| %>`